# Select index from listview

Tags: c#

I'm having some problem to get the index of the selected row in a listview. I wonder why this code isn't working? I get a red line below the SelectedIndex

```
    private void lvRegAnimals_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lvRegAnimals.SelectedIndex;
        string specialData = motelManager.GetInfoFromList(index);
        UppdateSpecialData(specialData);
    }
```

Help is preciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

For some strange reason I get two messages when I click on one of the lines in the listView!? First I get the previous number and then the number for the last clicked line. What could be wrong?

```
 private void lvRegAnimals_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lvRegAnimals.FocusedItem.Index;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(index));
    }
```

It's working now when I added a check like this:

```
if(lvRegAnimals.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
```

Comment: What value does lvRegAnimals.SelectedIndex return ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) doesn't contain any `SelectedIndex`, instead there is a property of `SelectedIndices`.

```
var indices = lvRegAnimals.SelectedIndices;
//indices[0] you can use that to access the first selected index
```

[ListView.SelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx)

> When the MultiSelect property is set to true, this property returns a
>   collection containing the indexes of all items that are selected in
>   the ListView. For a single-selection ListView, this property returns a
>   collection containing a single element containing the index of the
>   only selected item in the ListView.

Comment: Hmm, so there is no way to know which row the user has clicked on?

Comment: `indices[0]` will give you the selectedindex or if you are looking to get the focused item  You can use `lvRegAnimals.FocusedItem.Index`, see this link http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2010/02/c-how-to-get-selected-index-and.html

Comment: I just want to get the index of the row that the user click on, so that I can pass it like an index to a method to get some info from a list. I tested this: int intselectedindex = lvRegAnimals.SelectedIndices[0]; It works fine the first click, but on the second click on another row, the program crash!?

Comment: When I'm using lvRegAnimals.FocusedItem.Index it seems like I get both the last focused value and the the new value!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ, you should check if( lvRegAnimals.SelectedIndices.Count > 0) , and for `FocusedItem.Index`, it returns only a single value, how come you are getting two values

Comment: I just tested with a messagebox to display the index number, and yes it sounds strange, but it looks like it first showed the last focused index and then the new one! I have turned of VisualStudio and have to leave the computer, but I hope to solve this later

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Acquire SelectedItems reference.
        var selectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
        // Display text of first item selected.
        this.Text = selectedItems[0].Text;
        }
        else
        {
        // Display default string.
        this.Text = "Empty";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
listView1.FocusedItem.Index
```

This give you the index of the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread like this one, but here it goes again.

It can return NULL. Also the SelectedIndexChanged event can be FIRED TWICE. And the first time, there nothing selected yet.

So the only safe way to find it is like this:

```
    private void lv1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lv1.FocusedItem == null) return;
        int p = lv1.FocusedItem.Index;
```

... now int p has the correct value...

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is a darn hassle to work with sometimes.
A simple solution i've used is a for loop that checks for the
selected Item.

I've put my solution in the "When index change trigger" within the ListView.
Example:

```
int sel_item = 0; //an int to store the selected item index.
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
      {
             if (listView1.Items[i].Selected == true)
             {
              sel_item = i;
             }
      }
}
```

This would ofcourse only work correctly with the "Multiselection" option set as `false`.