# Why isn't 'SelectedIndex' defined on this ListView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview, selectedindex

I have created a `ListView` called `listUsers`, but for some reason `SelectedIndex` isn't defined.

[image]

And I have set the MultiSelect to false.

 [image]

It also seems suspicious to me that "False" is bolded. Meaning that it was not default.

This is not what I think I have been experiencing before.

So I find this very strange, and I don't know how to fix it.
I have tried so far (That didn't work):

- Restarted VS
- Copied a `ListView` from other forms, & pasted it on this form
- Deleted `this.listUsers.MultiSelect` definition from Designer's code

And none worked.
**What is going on?**

Additional details:

- Windows 7 32-bit
- VS2010
- Framework 4

Comment: No such property exists.

Comment: Such a property does exist, but for the ListView in UI.WebControls.

Comment: Be careful with the MSDN documentation. If you search for ListView, you might not end up with the [Systems.Windows.Forms.ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx). The first Google result is the [System.Windows.Controls.ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx), a WPF control that has in fact a `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: As always, your problem is you're using deprecated technology, when you should be using WPF. BTW, nice archeological SO Avatar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no selected index property on ListView in winforms. To get the selected index you can use

```
listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
```

Comment: There isn't? I was almost positive there is!!

...I need a rest.

Comment: @SmRndGuy I spent 3 days trying to figure out the problem  my visual studio had when I wanted to get the selected item in a list view and then I remembered stackoverflow... Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091400/get-single-listview-selecteditem) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324471/select-index-from-listview). They helped me.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the index of a row in ListView I'm using

```
 int myindex = Listview1.FocusedItem.Index;
```

It works.