# Search Xml file elements from Textbox and get result in listview C#

Tags: c#, xml, listview, search

On my program I have 2 forms. First one is to save information to xml file from textboxes and the second for is to search xml elements based on text that I write in textbox and show them in listview.

The problem is that when I get the results, in listview everything looks fine, but when I click the item in listview I get all information for xml element with index 0.

This is the code I use to search the xml and the code for SelectedindexChanged:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);


            XmlDocument cDoc = new XmlDocument();

            cDoc.Load(path + "\\MyProgram\\Data.xml");
            var doc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\MyProgram\\Data.xml");


            var q = from el in doc.Root.Elements("Register")
                    let str = el.Element("Name").Value
                    where str.ToLower().Equals(textBox1.Text)
                    select new ListViewItem(el.Elements().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());


            listView1.Items.AddRange(q.ToArray());
```

and for selectedIndexChange

```
 name.Text = History[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
 lastname.Text = History[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Lastname;
```

Please help me because it's begin a week that I'm searching for a solution.

Comment: 'q' is an array (ToArray()) so why are you doing AddRange(q.ToArray)?  If q is a string you are adding characters to the listView1.

Comment: There is no problem with listview. The only problem is that SelectedIndexChange is taking index number from XML file. For example after searching a name I have a result on Listview in the first row, the name in the XML is in index 5, but the first Row in listview has index 0, so when i click on it I have all information for index 0 on XML fil and this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `SelectedIndex` property of your ListView instead of `SelectedItems[0].Index`.

Update: With WinForms see this question [Why isn't 'SelectedIndex' defined on this ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358854/why-isnt-selectedindex-defined-on-this-listview):

```
listView1.SelectedIndices[0]
```

Comment: If you mean like this:
name.Text = History[listView1.SelectedIndex].Name;

It gives a error

Comment: listView doesn't have Selectedindex it has only selectedItems

Comment: I have tried this one also but again it gives the index of XML data file and not from listview.