# How to efficiently reset colour of previously selected items in a ListView

Tags: listview, c#-4.0

I have a ListView of items, and I've set MultipleSelect = false.

When the user clicks on an item in the list, I change the background colour.

But the problem is how do I reset the colour of the previously selected item if the user selects another item?

I know that I could keep track of the selected index, and when the user clicks again, to change the previous item's colour before setting and updating the new item.  But surely there must be ResetColours/ResetStyles method that I could call that would do the job?

Pointers much appreciated.

EDIT:

I ended up implementing the simple workaround (as mentioned above):

Code snippet below:

```
                if (myListView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (previouslySelectedItemIndex != -1)
                    {
                        // Clear what was selected before...
                        myListView.Items[previouslySelectedItemIndex].BackColor = Color.White;
                    }

                    selectedIndex = myListView.SelectedIndices[0];
                    myListView.Items[selectedIndex].BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                    previouslySelectedItemIndex = selectedIndex; // And make a note of what has been selected.
                }
```

And of course switching off screen updates via BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate()...  But is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

This [article explained why certain properties weren't available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324471/select-index-from-listview)
 - because I set MultipleSelect = false.

whilst [this didn't answer the question it posed](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/282232/HOW-TO-SELECT-CLEAR-SELECTION-IN-LISTVIEW-CONTROL).

I asked my question because this [microsoft article mentions the ResetStyles method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.resetstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but the implication was that I needed to cycle through all items in my listview??

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you want to change the ListViewIten background brush color on an item selection. If so, then I can suggest you to use triggers.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by brush color but the code I have to "set/reset" the color is: myListView.Items[myPreviouslySelectedItemIndex].BackColor = ....  Ie if I've selected something before (myListView.SelectedIndices[0] > -1) then I make a note of it so that next time round.....    Also not sure what you mean by Triggers - never used them before and sounds like overkill?

Comment: Golik: Code snippet added

Comment: No.  It's purely programmatic? I'm simply working with a Windows form that has some ListView controls, and in the code behind page, I'm trapping/handling the events of that form.

Comment: @Sai-LeungLee sorry my fault I've just thought that you are working with the wpf, very sorry if I've confused you.